# R- Beginner Level-Mutate and Filter

Tags: r

I am working with the dataset "polls_us_election_2016" , and I understand how to setup one condition using mutate and filter together. I could not formulate this question, I would be glad if someone help me?

Question1: Which polls (i) did not poll for vote intentions for Johnson, (ii) had a difference in raw
poll vote shares between Trump and Clinton greater than 5, and (iii) were done in the
state of Iowa?

My answer:

```
'mutate(polls_us_election_2016, trump_clinton_tot = rawpoll_trump - rawpoll_clinton & trump_clinton_tot < 5) %>%
+ select(-rawpoll_johnson, -adjpoll_johnson) %>%
+ filter(state %in% c("Iowa"))'
```

At which steps should I correct my answers because when I tried this; there is always "FALSE" or "TRUE" at "trump_clinton_tot" columns.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but `select(-rawpoll_johnson, -adjpoll_johnson)`  is de-selecting those columns rather  than finding missing values in those columns and filtering the dataset (use `filter` to filter the dataset).